# Error on create a new account from Hyperledger iroha using swift

Tags: ios, swift, hyperledger, hyperledger-iroha

I tried to download and build the `iroha-ios` from  [iroha iOS github](https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha-ios) then started to use the sample project to create a new account. I have deployed an `iroha` server on my PC. When I run the program, it prints out an error like this.

```
SwiftyIrohaExample.Iroha_Protocol_QueryResponse:
error_response {
  reason: STATEFUL_INVALID
  message: "query signatories did not pass validation"
}
```

When I checked the hash that is produced on the log in `Xcode`, it doesn't exist in the `iroha` system.
What step did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the libraries might not be up-to-date all the time. At the moment one of the maintainers fixed the library to work with develop branch. Here: https://bitbucket.org/Emkil/swiftyiroha/

Comment: tried to build that SwiftyIroha on simulator, it gives me this error  "The operation couldn’t be completed. (SwiftGRPC.RPCError error 0.) ". I have successfully created the iroha and trading cool coins. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @DarwinHarianto we have just checked the work of the library with the latest `dev` branch. Please try to use it - the error you receive seems likely to be caused by old Iroha version.

Comment: this is what I do, I open the bitbucket link. click on the this library and Hyperledger Iroha project (hyperlink). download the iOS file, then pod install. Then start the Hyperledger Iroha instance launched in Docker using the command at the bitbucket link. Start the iOS project. but it still gives me this error 
SwiftyIrohaExample.Iroha_Protocol_QueryResponse:
error_response {
  reason: STATEFUL_INVALID
  message: "query signatories did not pass validation"
}
query_hash: "288b15e6c3c89738b42daab52511dc762433f1f2837aab8be75c26da6d5ad4c5"

Comment: @DarwinHarianto, there was some outdated information in the ReadMe file - to make it work you need to take the genesis block from the dev branch. Please check out the updated readme.

Comment: downloaded from the dev branch, got new error from genesis.block 

[2019-01-17 07:43:45.696000400][th:12][error] MAIN Failed to parse genesis block

Comment: @DarwinHarianto I think this issue could be connected to something else. I think we could discuss this with the community step-by step with you in chat here: https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/iroha. Maybe the issue occurred because of the fact that genesis block version was not updated according to the current branch